# Data stored to the unknown collection

Tags: database, mongodb

I have created the database name as bitnomy and saving the data to the collection name transactionModel, but when I hit the request it save to some collection name transactionmodels (which is nowhere link).

Can any one help me in this?

Comment: More context is needed. Given what you are saying I suppose you are using mongoose, which by default pluralises the models name.

Comment: Hello , i got the answer, i am using mongoose, always take a collection name in small letters and add s to the end of the collection , so it automatically conerts the transactionModel to transactionmodels , for example if the collection name is "xyz", mongoose converts to "xyzs" and if we use the caps letter than it converts the name to all small letters.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using mongoose you can force the collection name during the Schema creation:

```
var UserInfo = new Schema({
  username : String,
  birthDate : Date
}, { collection: 'userinfo' });
```

This because by default mongoose pluralise the collection names, in this case would be `users`